# Why is Lubuntu reporting as "arch" in npm?

Tags: package-management, lubuntu, versions, nodejs, npm

I just installed jQuery via npm and was greeted with the following message:

```
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents
@1.1.1: wanted {"os": "darwin", "arch", "any"} (current: {"os": "linux", "arch": "x64
"})
```

I know that's probably just telling me that this fsevents version wants OSX (? Maybe darwin refers to OSX -- for some reason I have a vague idea it does?). I'm also assuming this has nothing to do with Arch Linux, but I'm wondering what the meaning of "darwin" and "arch" are in these contexts. I know this might seem a slightly frivolous question, as it's not really a problem, but I'd like to start contributing to Linux myself soon, so I'm becoming curious about the inner workings more than I was previously.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just realised it's probably short for architecture (i.e. 32bit vs 64bit), so if I'm right with my OSX guess, I suppose I just answered my own question.

Comment: yes, it has nothing to do with arch linux :)

Comment: Key, value pair "arch" and "x64" belong to eachother ;)

Comment: so darwin is a OSX base and arch refers to 64bit vs 32bit architecture, is that right?

Comment: Not quite. "arch" is the processor architecture. In your case it's "Intel x86 64 bit", but it could also be "ARM v7 little endian" for a Raspberry Pi, or "DEC Alpha" if you happen to have such a beast sitting in your basement.